# Tricks to avoid duplication of memory allocation when returning data.table or data.frame in R?

Tags: r, memory-management, return, data.table

I have created a function that is called to read in and then return a data.table:

```
read.in.data <- function(filename)
{
    library(data.table)
    data.holder<-read.table(filename, skip=1)
    return(data.table(data.holder))
}
```

I have noticed from observing my RAM as the function processes that R seems to process this in 2 steps (or at least this is my best guess for what's going on). For example, when I load a 1.5 GB file (15 columns with a total of 136 characters per row), R seems to 1) read in the data and use 1.5 GB of RAM, and then 2) use another 1.5 GB of RAM for the return.

Are there some tricks to creating a function to create a data.table (or data.frame for that matter) and return the data.table without requiring duplication in memory? Or must I do all processing for the data.table within the function where the table is created?

Observations:
If I run this code twice in a row, the memory is not cleared; since I only have 8 GB of RAM, the function fails. If I skip the step of storing the "read.table" in a variable (as shown below), I don't get any benefit. I wouldn't want to do this any way, since I'd like to have the ability to clean up the data.table before returning it. A fix to my problem would also enable me to process larger files without running out of memory.

```
short.read.trk <- function(fntrk)
{
    library(data.table)
    return(data.table(read.table(fntrk, skip=1)))
}
```

Comment: I feel your pain. Try fread() in v1.8.7.  It creates a data.table directly so the (copying) data.table() wrapper can be avoided, plus it's more efficient than read.table anyway (even with all known tricks applied).

Comment: Thank you, I will try fread() as soon as 1.8.7 has a build on r-forge (currently lists as "failed to build").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory savings is mostly what you're after, you could convert it one column at a time:

```
library(data.table)
read.in.data <- function(filename)
{
  data.holder <- read.table(filename, skip=1)
  dt <- data.table(data.holder[[1]])
  names(dt) <- names(data.holder)[1]
  data.holder[[1]] <- NULL

  for(n in names(data.holder)) {
    dt[, `:=`(n, data.holder[[n]]) ]
    data.holder[[n]] <- NULL
  }
  return(dt)
}
```

(untested)

It won't be any faster, in fact it's probably slower.  But it should be less wasteful of memory.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting approach. I will implement it when I have access to the data set on Monday, and edit this comment with the results.

Comment: +1 Interesting approach. That might actually be very quick. Other approaches to test are `as.data.table()` rather than `data.table()` and (for experts only): `setattr(data,"class",c("data.frame","data.table"))`.

Comment: +1 I like the approach of using "NULL" to keep the memory low. I have given it a try when binding tables together. For example, I tried it using something like dt<-do.call("rbind",list(dt,dt.holder)) followed by dt.holder<-NULL. However, the above approach did not change the overall RAM used. When comparing my original script with the one proposed, the RAM usage was the same.

Comment: Docuemada - for `rbind`, you'd have to create each column one by one, assigning `NULL` after *each* column creation, not just at the end.

Comment: @KenWilliams Thank you. This might explain my large memory fluctuations. As I am new to R, could you explain why you needed to put the := in single quotes?

Comment: ":=" is the update operator defined in data.table, It updates by reference, I suggest you read the 2 vignettes provided with the package as a first step.